# Stock Android 6 (Motorola Moto G 3rd gen) has no 'Exchange ActiveSync' account option

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, active-sync, motorola-moto-g3

I own a Motorola Moto G 3rd generation that's running Android 6 Marshmallow.

I'm trying to do two way contacts/calendar syncing with my outlook.com account.

By using the Microsoft Outlook app, one way syncing is working, but that's not good enough.

Most tutorials I find talk about adding a 'Exchange ActiveSync' account to 'Accounts' under 'Settings'. However, I don't have this choice.

Why is this? What should I use instead?

Comment: I have a stock Moto G 3rd Gen, a few actually... You don't need a 3rd party app at all, if you to Settings - Accounts the first option is the Gmail icon with the word Exchange next to add, just add the account there, this gives mail, calendar, and contact sync. If you have a 3rd party app installed, you may have to remove it and the account first. If it doesn't show up, something is missing or disabled and I would consider a factory default.

Answer (score 0):

http://vodafone.intelliresponse.com/index.jsp?id=1593&question=Set+up+Hotmail%2FOutlook+as+an+Exchange+account+on+your+Android+device&requestType=NormalRequest&source=100

The trick is picking manual and then Exchange. The link above walks you through the screens. Won't be exact but close enough.

Ken